# Dynamic appbar icon WP8

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm going to implement showing text inside the circle of appbar icon. For example, user presses some button on the screen and the number in circle appbar icon increases like a counter.

I see the only way to implement it: generate dynamically the icon with the number and update the icon in appbar. Does anybody have such experience? Looks like it's possible, but I don't know how to do that.

Would dynamic icon generation require much time on runtime? Which tools (libraries) could help me in generating appbar icon dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can render bitmap from control witch contains text. You can use

> WitableBitmap

. Then you save local img and set  it path as source

> IconUri